# Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST in kohana 3.2

Tags: php, mysql, kohana-3

I am getting this `Fatal error: Cannot re-assign auto-global variable _POST error in kohana 3.2` in windows 7 environment but the same script runs with out any error in linux. I have no idea on this. Any solution will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there a line number? Example code? Looks like you're trying to reassign `$_POST` which is reserved in PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it runs on Linux, but in Win get fail - see PHP version. Since PHP 5.4, you cannot use a superglobal as the parameter to a function. [See remark](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php#112184)

**EDIT**

> Parameter names that shadow super globals now cause a fatal error. This prohibits code like function foo($_GET, $_POST) {}.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration54.incompatible.php

Comment: Might want to include an example in your answer. PHP manual comments have been known to vanish

Comment: @Phil updated anwser.

Comment: @voodoo417 its about the PHP version.. i have changed the version and it works now